# How can I select data from a mysql table, and then throw it into a html table

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to draw data from a table in my mysql, and put the data into a customized table. I would like to have the info into the table as http://gyazo.com/c6a40fcd6e4edc66f7f11650f641dae2. However when I'm trying it turns out very bad. Heres my coding.

```php
<?php
$servername = "#";
$username = "#";
$password = "#";
$dbname = "#";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT minecraft_user, service FROM votes";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
         echo '<div class="grid-40 vote-leaderboard"> <h3><i class="fa fa-star"></i>Recent Votes</h3> <table class="top-voters"> <tbody>';

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo '<tr><td>' . $row[minecraft_user]. '</td><td>' . $row[service]. '</td></tr><br>';
     }
} else {
     echo "No recent votes!";
}
         echo '</tbody>';

$conn->close();
?>
```

Can someone please help me with this? I've been testing for hours with no result.

Comment: What is the error you getting from the above code ?

Comment: Not getting any error, however its showing as http://gyazo.com/9e32569f20baafb15b19209995c8ecaf. I have changed the code slightly however.

Comment: Are you refreshing the page to get the next result or what ?

Comment: If you are using the mysqli code even after the code you posted . You should remove the `$conn->close();` connection close.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I've done that and now how do I get rid of the gap that I linked in the comment above?

Comment: You are having a `<div>`  or `<br>` before your php code and that makes the gap :). You should remove it that too

Comment: Every time you refresh the page, I want it to get the last 10 table entrys.

Comment: Yes then you should change your query accordingly. Shall i help you in that ?

Comment: If its not a bother, then please. I have also fixed the gap that I had created.

Comment: May i see your html code ?

Comment: then probably your first entry should have no details in your database I have posted the query what you need to change to get the last 10 entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the last 10 table entries then you should change your sql query like this

```
$sql = "SELECT minecraft_user, service FROM votes order by `minecraft_user` DESC limit 0,10";
```

If you add id as `auto_increment` then

```
$sql = "SELECT id, minecraft_user, service FROM votes order by `id` DESC limit 0,10";
```

Comment: Didn't work at first, however added an id section to my table, and ordered  by that. Seems to work. That you.

Comment: yes, and the `id` should be set as `auto_increment`